# Headers needing each other

Tags: c++, class, header, include, dependencies

This question is closed because it is considered a duplicate of:

1. [C++ cyclical header dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239943/c-cyclical-header-dependency)
2. [cyclic dependency between header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089056/cyclic-dependency-between-header-files)
3. [C++ error: 'Line2' has not been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058363/c-error-line2-has-not-been-declared/5058627#5058627)

However the other question are different from my: they ask a different case and the answer do not work with my problem. Their answer suggest to put the function into a `.cpp` file and to define the class before to declare it. I cannot put the function in `.cpp` because my class is a template, and I already define the class, but it is not useful.

---

I have two header file `a.h` and `b.h`. In they are defined two template class `A` and `B`.

A function of `A` need work with object of `B` and viceversa. Since they are template class, I can not put the function in `.cpp` file, it must stay in header, and I have a big headache because of the order of the inclusion.

What is a good methodology to solve this problem?

Currently I move function definition around and find a way to include the headers in the correct order, but this become always more complex. Moreover I do not like to have function definition far from class declaration (for example in other file).

---

Example code:

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"
template< typename T > class B;

template< typename T >
class A {
public:
    B<void> *b;
    void f();
    void g();
};
template< typename T > void A<T>::f() {
    std::cout << "A::f" << std::endl;
    b->f();
}
template< typename T > void A<T>::g() {
    std::cout << "A::g" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
template< typename T > class A;

template< typename T >
class B {
public:
    A<void> *a;
    void f();
    void g();
};
template< typename T > void B<T>::f( ) {
    std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl;
}
template< typename T > void B<T>::g( ) {
    std::cout << "B::g" << std::endl;
    a->g();
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int main( ) {
    A<void> a;
    B<void> b;
    a.b = &b;
    b.a = &a;

    a.f();
    b.g();

    return 0;
}
```

This not work because `a.h` include `b.h`. `b.h` then can not include `a.h` and thus `B::g` is error.

For this example code I can move `B::g` in `main.cpp` or at the end of `a.h`, but with more complex program this is not easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239943/c-cyclical-header-dependency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089056/cyclic-dependency-between-header-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058363/c-error-line2-has-not-been-declared/5058627#5058627 <-- Dupes

Comment: Show us some **minimal** code, unfortunately there's no shortcut to solving this.

Comment: @BillyONeal: no, my case is different because my class are template: I can not put the declaration of the function in source file, and also to declare the class (`class A;`) not solve my problem.

Comment: @RitardiGiuseppe: Why not? You can declare class templates just like you declare classes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code compiles as-is on my Visual C++. The reason is that compiler does not look "inside" a function until it is actually called, i.e. until `main.cpp` in your case.

Frankly, I'm not sure if this is guaranteed by the standard. In case it isn't, you can always split your headers to "independent" and "dependent" portions, like this:

**a_forward.h**

```
#ifndef A_FORWARD_H
#define A_FORWARD_H

template< typename T > class B;

template< typename T >
class A {
public:
    B<T> *b;
    void f();
    void g();
};

#endif
```

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>
#include "a_forward.h"
#include "b_forward.h"

template< typename T > void A<T>::f() {
    std::cout << "A::f" << std::endl;
    b->f();
}

template< typename T > void A<T>::g() {
    std::cout << "A::g" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

**b_forward.h**

```
#ifndef B_FORWARD_H
#define B_FORWARD_H

template< typename T > class A;

template< typename T >
class B {
public:
    A<T> *a;
    void f();
    void g();
};

#endif
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>
#include "a_forward.h"
#include "b_forward.h"

template< typename T > void B<T>::f( ) {
    std::cout << "B::f" << std::endl;
}

template< typename T > void B<T>::g( ) {
    std::cout << "B::g" << std::endl;
    a->g();
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
---||---
```

Comment: "Frankly, I'm not sure if this is guaranteed by the standard." I'm sure. **It's not**. In fact it's quite the opposite: two-phase lookup requires doing at least some checking on the first pass. Now, it can't instantiate the template on the first pass, so it's possible that it will compile on a conformant compiler. But you can't rely on the compiler to look ignore template pre-instantiation.